# Reference Salesforce "Files" in formula fields and emails

Tags: files

We all love Static Resource, but there is huge limitation - the file size cannot be more than 5mb. For most JS files, it is OK, but not so good if you are storing images, even when you zip them up.

I like Salesforce Files because file size can be 2GB! But there is another problem with that, we cannot reference the files and contents within the file in formula fields like we can for static resource.

Other problem with Files is, we can upload them to any record but cannot attach same file when sending email. Notes and Attachment is replaced by Files, and I believe "ContentVersion" id should be supported as well when sending email.

Wondering how others are using Files given above limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here for anybody who stumbles across this post in the future.  For formula references, you *can* refer to a File according to this knowledge article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385501&type=1

Unfortunately, currently don't know the answer to the other question about using Files in an email.